# Spring + javax.ws produces only json for a list output, how to get it as xml?

Tags: java, json, xml, spring

I have an endpoint that used to produce a very nicely formatted xml for parsing on my client application.

The method on my `@RestController` is:

```
@GET
@RequestMapping("/alerts/list/{companyId}/{agentId}/{pollInterval}/{lastExecutionDate}")
@Produces(XML_CONTENT_TYPE)
public List<Alert>  listAlertsByAgentId(@PathVariable String companyId, 
        @PathVariable String agentId, 
        @PathVariable String pollInterval, 
        @PathVariable String lastExecutionDate) throws IOException, Exception {

    Agent agent = getService().findAgentById(agentId);
    agent.setPollInterval(Integer.parseInt(pollInterval));

    int year = Integer.parseInt(lastExecutionDate.substring(0, 4));
    int month = Integer.parseInt(lastExecutionDate.substring(4, 6)) - 1;
    int date = Integer.parseInt(lastExecutionDate.substring(6, 8));
    int hour = Integer.parseInt(lastExecutionDate.substring(8, 10));
    int minute = Integer.parseInt(lastExecutionDate.substring(10, 12));
    int second = Integer.parseInt(lastExecutionDate.substring(12, 14));

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(year, month, date, hour, minute, second);

    agent.setLastExecutionDate(cal.getTime());

    getService().updateAgent(agent);
    List<Alert> list = fetchAlertListByAgentId(companyId, agentId);

    if(list == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return list;
    } 
}
```

When I was using `XStream` I used to parse the list result, but it now it only returns a JSON string.

How to force it to XML?

Comment: You can refer this article: http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/05/xml-response-with-responsebody.html

Comment: @Minh, thanks for the suggestion. Still no luck.